# Forçar a cor no app java android studio

Tags: java, android

Oi eu estou fazendo um app em java android studio, eu queria deixar a cor de fundo que eu escolhe, mas no meu celular que tem modo escuro ele muda as cores, como faço para deixar normal ?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente no XML de tema está definido como (provavelmente localizado em `main/res/values/styles.xml`):

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
```

Mude para `false` ou você também pode fazer isso via script setando para false o [`setForceDarkAllowed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setForceDarkAllowed(boolean)) (API level 29)